# Filtrar por usuario y calcular columna con el porcentaje que representa ese resultado del total

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

tengo un problema para lograr hacer una query que haga lo siguiente:

Filtrando las órdenes confirmadas, calcular a nivel usuario el porcentaje de órdenes
confirmadas, que tienen entre los “Top 100” restaurantes (según cantidad de órdenes
confirmadas)

Debería quedar algo así

| user_id | ordenes_confirmadas | ordenes_confirm_top_100_rest | ratio(%)_ordenes_top_100_rest |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 10 | 4 | 40% |

La tabla que tengo que usar tiene los siguientes datos

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFMYl.png

Mi codigo base hasta ahora

```
SELECT
user_id as 'user_id',
count(user_id) as 'conf_orders'
FROM orders
WHERE state_name = 'CONFIRMED'
GROUP BY user_id
```

Alguno me podría dar una mano?

CREATE TABLE `orders` (
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`order_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`delivered_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`country` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`city` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`restaurant_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`user_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`delivery_address` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`order_amount` double DEFAULT NULL,
`order_tax_amount` double DEFAULT NULL,
`state_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
KEY `orders_id_IDX` (`id`) USING BTREE,
KEY `orders_country_IDX` (`country`) USING BTREE,
KEY `orders_order_date_IDX` (`order_date`) USING BTREE,
KEY `orders_restaurant_id_IDX` (`restaurant_id`) USING BTREE,
KEY `orders_user_id_IDX` (`user_id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema? Si es posible, [crea un fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) con un ejemplo mínimo y verificable. De poco sirve una imagen, si alguien tuviera que ayudarte y quisiera hacer pruebas sobre el código tendría que adivinar tus CREATE TABLE, y meter los datos a mano... es mucho más simple si nos das todo eso hecho, puesto que tienes a mano los datos y toda la información necesaria.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: @A.Cedano Gracias por responder, te adjunto los codigos de los CREATE TABLE